# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

Tags: java, sockets, socket-timeout-exception

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this exception?

Ftp server running public IP, so when I try to access server and then download file that time the download file size is 0 byte only.

Showing this Exception

```
  ERROR [FTPClient] 7 Mar 2014 17:08:53.703 : Caught and rethrowing exception in getDataAfterInitGet() : Accept timed out
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
            at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.acceptConnection(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:185)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.getInputStream(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:212)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getInputStream(FTPClient.java:3308)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getDataAfterInitGet(FTPClient.java:3341)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getData(FTPClient.java:3274)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getFile(FTPClient.java:3061)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.get(FTPClient.java:2445)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.downloadFile(FileTransferClient.java:752)
    at ftpclientresumedownload.ResumeDownload.main(ResumeDownload.java:110)
```

In localhost, it downloads perfectly, but in public it is throwing Exception.
Why does this happen? Please provide some clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: let me use my crystal ball here to guess how the code looks like (if there is any) :-)

Comment: Remote host drops connection due to firewall restrictions ?

Comment: I'm gonna guess firewall issues as well, it usually is. Perhaps you have to pass through a proxy?